# MSKLC : How to associate a country to a custom keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I made a custom keyboard layout with MSKLC.
I thought I followed the instructions carefully and [chose appropriate values](https://github.com/springcomp/optimized-azerty-win/blob/master/KBFRZ71.klc#L7-L9) for the `LOCALENAME` and `LOCALID` parameters.

However, in the switch-keyboard popup that is displayed by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or on the TaskBar, the country associated with my custom layout is not displayed.

[image]

How to I author my layout so that Windows knows about the country it should be associated with?

Comment: A keyboard layout is associated with a language, and not the other way around. You need to install your language first, and only afterward install the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. So my layout is associated with an existing language 'FR'. What should I do to make it displayed ? What do you mean by "installing a language first" ?

Comment: You did write : "the **country** associated with my custom layout is not displayed". So I don't understand.

Comment: @harrymc see the screenshot? Instead of my question mark overlay, I would like "FR" being displayed.

Comment: Does the question mark stand for your keyboard?

Comment: Yes exactly. You can find a reference to the source code of the keyboard in the message.